# Trouble with Named Pipes

Tags: php, python, pipe, named-pipes

I am new to using php and python but I have a task that I am trying to complete and the test code I have does not seem to work. Basically I am trying to get data from an html form (using php) to a python script for processing. After looking at some really useful stuff from other posts I have decided to use pipes. To test the process I have used the following code.

php code:

```
<?php
$pipe = fopen('Testpipe','r+');
fwrite($pipe, 'Test');
fclose($pipe);
?>
```

Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
pipeName = 'Testpipe'
try:
    os.unlink(pipeName)
except:
    pass
os.mkfifo(pipeName)
pipe = open(pipeName, 'r')
while True:
    data = pipe.readline()
    if data != '':
         print repr(data)
```

When I run the Python code I can see the pipe being created in the directory using ls -l but when I use my browser to run the php script (I am running a webserver on a raspberry pi) nothing happens. It has got me a little confused as most of the posts I read state how simple pipes are to get going. I assume on opening the browser (php script through the server) I should see the text come up in the python shell?

Any help would be appreciated.

Ok further to my original post I have modified my original code thanks to alot of trawling through the net and some really useful Python tutorials. I now have something that proves the principal of pipes although I still have to resolve the php side of things but I feel as though I'm getting there now. Revised code is below:

```
import os,sys

pipe_name = 'testpipe'

def child():
    pipeout = os.open(pipe_name, os.O_WRONLY)
    while True:
         time.sleep(1)
         os.write(pipeout, 'Test\n')

def parent():
    pipein = open(pipe_name, 'r')
    while True:
         line = pipein.readline()[:-1]
         print 'Parent %d got "%s"' %(os.getpid(),line)

if not os.path.exists(pipe_name):
    os.mkfifo(pipe_name)
pid = os.fork()
if pid != 0:
    parent()
else:
    child()
```

This has got me on the path to where I want to go so hopefully it may be of use to someone having similar questions.

Comment: why are you using python and php, either one could do this and using just the one is less problematic

Comment: Hi Dagon, It's part of a uni project so I have to use both and as I haven't used either php or python before It gives me a chance to learn them.

Answer (score 0):

try to provide an absolute path ("/tmp/TestPipe") to be sure that both are looking to the same file.

Comment: Hi Louis, Thanks for the suggestion, I just tried it and unfortunately it made no difference. I guess I am expecting the testpipe text to show in the Python shell if it works?

Comment: I just tried writing to a standard text file from the same php code and all worked well so the location seems fine.

Comment: Having played around with the Python code a bit it seems as though the problem relates to the: `data = pipe.readline()` line although I can't see exactly what the problem is - Any ideas?

Comment: Python readline waits for an end of line. So maybe add \n to end of fwrite in php  : fwrite($pipe,'Test\n')

Comment: Didn't seem to make any difference unfortunately.